# Special characters in rowid in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

When I run the following command on my oracle database I get the value of row_id with special characters. For eg: row_id = *BB170egLyghDYQwXPUdQY1b+

```
SELECT rowid as row_id FROM table_name WHERE id = 123456
```

Why is this row_id coming as a non hexadecimal string? I beleive rowid is always stored as a hexadecimal string. Is there a way to convert this string into the correct rowid format?

I have tried using the below to convert to hexadecimal, but it does not work as the length exceeds 10.

```
ResultSet rs = jdbc.executeQuery(query);    
String str = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(rs.getRowId(1).getBytes())
```

Comment: I'm not sure ROWID is hex. According to [this wiki](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ROWID) it is a sequence of 8 or 10 bytes (depending on your oracle version) which _when printed_ is displayed using hex. What you have might as well be base64 encoded bytes.

Comment: `rowid` is `base64`-string, not `HEX`. See [`rowid` data type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-AEF1FE4C-2DE5-4BE7-BB53-83AD8F1E34EF)

Answer (score 0):

The ROWID is a pseudocolumn that is unique for each row in a table. It is hidden from description of a table so DESC tab_name will not show it. It is selectable,though, and when selected the result shown is a Base64 string. It looks like here:

```sql
Select ROWID, DEPTNO, ENAME From emp Where DEPTNO = 30
ROWID               DEPTNO  ENAME
------------------  ------  -----------
AABRFrAAEAADnz2AAB      30  ALLEN
AABRFrAAEAADnz2AAC      30  WARD
AABRFrAAEAADnz2AAE      30  MARTIN
AABRFrAAEAADnz2AAF      30  BLAKE
AABRFrAAEAADnz2AAJ      30  TURNER
AABRFrAAEAADnz2AAL      30  JAMES
```

One of the options to get something usable from ROWID is explained **[here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/931/Decoding-the-Oracle-ROWID-and-some-Base64-for-fun.html)** and if we put it in the above query we'll get this:

```sql
Select 
    ROWID, 
    UTL_ENCODE.Base64_Decode(UTL_RAW.Cast_To_Raw(ROWID)) "ROWID_DECODED",
    UTL_ENCODE.Base64_Decode(UTL_RAW.Cast_To_Raw(LPAD(SUBSTR(ROWID, 16, 3), 4, 'A'))) "BLOCK",
    To_Number(UTL_ENCODE.Base64_Decode(UTL_RAW.Cast_To_Raw(LPAD(SubStr(ROWID, 16, 3), 4, 'A'))), 'XXXXXX') "ROWSLOT",
    DEPTNO, ENAME 
From emp 
Where DEPTNO = 30

ROWID               ROWID_DECODED               BLOCK   ROWSLOT   DEPTNO  ENAME
------------------  --------------------------  ------  -------   ------  ------
AABRFrAAEAADnz2AAB  00005116B0001000039F3D8000  000001        1       30    ALLEN
AABRFrAAEAADnz2AAC  00005116B0001000039F3D8000  000002        2       30    WARD
AABRFrAAEAADnz2AAE  00005116B0001000039F3D8000  000004        4       30    MARTIN
AABRFrAAEAADnz2AAF  00005116B0001000039F3D8000  000005        5       30    BLAKE
AABRFrAAEAADnz2AAJ  00005116B0001000039F3D8000  000009        9       30    TURNER
AABRFrAAEAADnz2AAL  00005116B0001000039F3D8000  00000B       11       30    JAMES
```

Comment: I don't think that the `block` is correct as long as this small table should not occupy multiple blocks (assuming default block size of 8Kb it should fit into a single block). Possibly it would be better to use `DBMS_ROWID`. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zhQHu0yN)

Comment: @astentx I'm not sure, but the ROWID for just created table and inserted rows is like in your fiddle. This is an very old emp table where there was some deletions and insertions. So, maybe , if yyou try  to delete some recs and reinsert the same one again after some time - ??? I was just applied part of the code explained in the link above...

Comment: I've added your calculations to my just created table and it increments block number for each row. Unfortunately, I didn't perform manual calculations on rowid, only by this auxiliary package.